# FPDF Draw a rectangle in given area

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I have a list of competitors in a championship. Now it looks like this

[image]

but I want to draw some rectangles like in this image

[image]

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // header-footer
}
$pdf = new PDF();    
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','U',12);
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
for($j=0;$j<sizeof($idscat);$j++) {
    // new pdf page dor a new category
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($idscat[$j]);$i++) {
         // inserting rectangles with names
         $pdf->Cell(50,10,$z.". ".$idscat[$j][$i]["nume"].' '.$idscat[$j][$i]["prenume"],1,1);
                $pdf->Ln(2);
    }
}
```